# Using a Superclass's getClass method from a Subclass object

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a total of three classes. Main, Animal (Superclass) and Cat (Subclass). 
When I tried to call the whatIsTheClass() method, I didn't understand the output "Cat". I was expecting to see the output "Animal". The reason why I expected the output "Animal" is because I believe the method whatIsTheClass() is called from an Animal object and not a Cat object as the Subclass does not contain this method.

Main class:

```
package com.example.java;

public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Animal cat = new Cat();
 }

}
```

Cat class:

```
package com.example.java;

public class Cat extends Animal {

 public Cat() {
     super();
     whatIsTheClass();
 }

}
```

Animal class:

```
package com.example.java;

public class Animal {

 public void whatIsTheClass() {
     System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
 }

}
```

My understanding is that in inheritance, the Subclass does not copy the methods from the Superclass. If the called to method is not defined in the Subclass object, it will look for the called to method in the Superclass object. And if the called to method is defined in the Superclass object, it will be called from there. In this case, because the Subclass does not define it's own whatIsTheClass() method, it must have used the whatIsTheClass() method that is defined in the Superclass object. But if whatIsTheClass() was called from the Superclass object, why did it return the name of the Subclass rather than the name of the Superclass?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. That's not, at all, how polymorphism works. Your object is a Cat. Cat inherits the `whatIsTheClass` method from its superclass. `this` is the current object, and the currrent object is a cat (since you created it using `new Cat()`), so its class is Cat. When you create a Cat you create a **single** object. This object is a Cat, and is also an Animal (since Cat extends Animal). You don't create two objects.

Comment: I am aware of the object stated in "Animal cat = new Cat();" being a Cat object. I am creating two objects because I am calling Super(); The second object is the Superclass object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `whatIsTheClass` may be defined in `Animal`, but in which class's code `getClass()` is called makes no difference.  It's all about the runtime type of the object, as stated in the [Javadocs for `getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()):

> Returns the runtime class of this `Object`.

The runtime type of the object specified by `cat` is `Cat`.

This is also why no class has to override `getClass()` just to return the proper `Class` object.  (The method `getClass()` is `final` anyway.)

Comment: To my understanding, when calling the whatIsTheClass method you are calling it in the Animal object because it is not defined in the Cat object. Wouldn't that mean the runtime type would be Animal? I have found the following in another post on stackoverflow that would possibly support my thoughts "Java recursively looks up methods one class at a time. The first matching method is called.

In general, the actual code within a method is not copied when you inherit from a class containing that method." So wouldn't THIS OBJECT be Animal? As it's executed in the Animal object?

Comment: No, the static type (compile time type) is `Animal`, from the type of `cat`.  The runtime type is `Cat`, from `new Cat()`.  Again, it's not _where_ `getClass()` is called, it's about the runtime type of the object.

Comment: I understand that the Runtime type of Animal cat is Cat. But what I am saying, which I might be wrong about, is that on runtime it does not contain the method whatIsTheClass(). To my understanding, this method only exists in the Superclass object and because of the inheritance it will execute the method in the Superclass object during runtime (which is of runtime type Animal) rather than executing the method in the Subclass object because that object does not have the method whatIsTheClass().

Answer (score 0):

When an object of Cat class is created, a copy of the all methods and fields of the superclass acquire memory in this object. That is why, by using the object of the subclass you can also access the members of a superclass.
Please note that during inheritance only object of subclass is created, not the superclass.

Comment: But by calling Super(); am I not calling to the constructor of the Superclass and creating a Superclass object that holds the methods and fields?

Comment: No, It will just initialize the properties of `this` object which refers to object of class Cat.

Comment: But if I call Super(); and in the constructor of the Superclass I assign a Superclass field to 1 and then output the value of that field I get the value 1 returned. This would not be possible without the creation of a Superclass object. Are you sure Super(); does not create a superclass object?